# Symfony - Multienviroment support for Envelope

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-4.3, enqueue

I'm using enqueue-dev + messenger-enqueue-transport in symfony 4.3 (where i have multiple enviroments (.env)) with beanstalk.

How should i setup it so jobs from different enviroments don't get mixed in the same queue? (as beanstalk server is the same)

I run the jobs of each enviroment using:

```
APP_ENV=qa bin/console messenger:consume beanstalk -vvv
APP_ENV=production bin/console messenger:consume beanstalk -vvv
```

When i was using pheanstalk without Smyfony i just added a suffix on jobs name, but in symfony jobs are set using classes:

```
$message = new ReportMessage($reportUrl);
$this->bus->dispatch((new Envelope($message))->with(new DelayStamp(1000)));
```

(my old implementation):

```
$this->pheanstalk->useTube(JOB_REPORT_MESSAGE . APP_ENV)->put(json_encode($data));
```

I've tried:
`config/packages/enqueue.yaml`:

```
enqueue:
    default:
        transport: '%env(resolve:ENQUEUE_DSN)%'
        client:
            router_topic: QA
```

`config/packages/messenger.yaml`:

```
framework:
   messenger:
    transports:
        beanstalk: enqueue://default?topic[name]=QA
```

And also:
`config/packages/enqueue.yaml`:

```
enqueue:
    default:
        transport: '%env(resolve:ENQUEUE_DSN)%'
        client:
            default_queue: QA
            router_queue: QA
```

`config/packages/messenger.yaml`:

```
framework:
   messenger:
    transports:
        beanstalk: enqueue://default?queue[name]=QA
```

But then no messages are consumed by messenger:consume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both queue & topic must be set:

config/packages/enqueue.yaml:

```
enqueue:
    default:
        transport: '%env(resolve:ENQUEUE_DSN)%'
        client:
            default_queue: QA
            router_queue: QA
            router_topic: QA
```

config/packages/messenger.yaml:

```
framework:
   messenger:
    transports:
        beanstalk: enqueue://default?queue[name]=QA&topic[name]=QA
```